# FizzBuzz... with style (js, jquery, html, css) (and questions...)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fizzbuzz

I discovered the FizzBuzz test while looking up something else on stackoverflow, so I decided to try it and see what I would come up with. I'm kind of new to jquery and JavaScript, so I'm looking for a critique on my code. What can I do better? Changes? Simplifications?

My priorities on this were -

1. Maintainability & readability
2. A page that was responsive to browser resizing & different screen sizes
3. Presenting it in a nice format without overdoing it. I came up with a simple, 4 column static version in about 45 minutes, but then refactored and styled it quite a bit.

Two additional notes:

1. I used the *defer* attribute in my script tag and put it in the head.

   ```
   <script src="fizzbuzz.js" charset="utf-8" defer="defer"></script>
   ```

   Is that acceptable? Is there a better way?
2. Setting intervals/timeouts still confounds me. How would you create a small interval between each number line printing, such that they print out sequentially and in an animated manner. I think you would need setInterval() or setTimeout(), but I'm not really sure how to use it without breaking everything.

Here's a copy of the code, edited per st88's suggestion. The old calculateColumns() function is commented out, and has been replaced by two functions (i.e. *createColumns* and *calculateColumns*) that deal with the conditional differently and remove a repeating code error.

```js
var fizzContainer = $("div.number-container");

var divisor1 = 3,
  divisor2 = 5,
  maxFizz = 100,
  word1 = "Fizz",
  word2 = "Buzz",
  windowWidth = window.innerWidth,
  minNumOfColumns = 1,
  maxNumOfColumns = 12,
  widthPerColumn = 150,
  columns,
  linesPerColumn,
  columnSizingParameters = {};

calculateHeading(windowWidth);
calculateColumns();
createColumns();

$(window).resize(function() {
  windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
  calculateHeading(windowWidth);

  $(".number-container").replaceWith("<div class='number-container'></div>");
  createColumns();
});

function calculateHeading(windowSize) {
  if (windowSize <= 500) {
    $("h1").attr("class", "transition xSmallHeading");
  } else if (windowSize <= 700) {
    $("h1").attr("class", "transition smallHeading");
  } else if (windowSize <= 1000) {
    $("h1").attr("class", "transition mediumHeading");
  } else if (windowSize >= 1000) {
    $("h1").attr("class", "transition largeHeading");
  }
}


// function calculateColumns() {
//    for (var i = 1; i <= maxNumOfColumns; i++) {
//       if ((windowWidth >= columnSizingParameters[i]) && (windowWidth <= columnSizingParameters[i + 1])) {
//            columns = i;
//            break;
//       }
//    }
//    linesPerColumn = Math.ceil(maxFizz / columns);
//    createNumbers();
// }

function calculateColumns() {
  var columnIt = minNumOfColumns - 1;
  for (columnIt; columnIt <= maxNumOfColumns; columnIt++) {
    columnSizingParameters[columnIt] = columnIt * widthPerColumn;
  }
}

function createColumns() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= maxNumOfColumns; ++i) {
    if (columnSizingParameters[i] > windowWidth) {
      columns = i - 1;
      break;
    }
  }
  linesPerColumn = Math.ceil(maxFizz / columns);
  createNumbers();
}

function createNumbers() {
  var i = 1;

  for (var c = 1; c <= columns; c++) {
    var col = $('<div></div').appendTo(".number-container");
    col.addClass('column');

    for (var a = 1; a <= linesPerColumn && i <= maxFizz; a++, i++) {
      if ((i % divisor1 === 0) && (i % divisor2 === 0)) {
        createContentLine(word1 + word2, "double-match", col, i, true);
        continue;
      } else if (i % divisor1 === 0) {
        createContentLine(word1, "match-1", col, i, true);
        continue;
      } else if (i % divisor2 === 0) {
        createContentLine(word2, "match-2", col, i, true);
        continue;
      } else {
        createContentLine(i, "num", col, i, false);
        continue;
      }
    }
  }
}

function createContentLine(toPrint, cssClass, col, i, appendNumToWord) {
  var contentLine = $("<p>" + toPrint + "</p>").appendTo(col);
  contentLine.addClass(cssClass);

  if (appendNumToWord) {
    var appendedNumber = $("<span></span").appendTo(contentLine);
    appendedNumber.text(" • " + i).addClass("num");
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
h1 {
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Berkshire Swash', cursive;
}
.transition {
  transition: 500ms;
}
/* Screen width Less than 500px */

.xSmallHeading {
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  padding: 15px;
}
/* Less than 700px */

.smallHeading {
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  padding: 20px;
}
/* Less than 1000px */

.mediumHeading {
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
/* Greater than 1000px */

.largeHeading {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.number-container {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 150px);
}
.column {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid lightblue;
}
.column:last-of-type {
  border-right: none;
}
.num {
  color: #585858;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.double-match {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #3f89d6;
  font-family: 'Crimson Text', serif;
}
.match-1,
.match-2 {
  font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.match-1 {
  color: #7ac962;
}
.match-2 {
  color: #ba62d4
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>FizzBuzz in Javascript</title>

  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Berkshire+Swash|Crimson+Text:600|Josefin+Slab:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="fizzbuzz.js" charset="utf-8" defer="defer"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <h1>The fizzbuzz test...in Javascript!</h1>

    <div class="number-container">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I also put it on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/AlessiaNyx/full/reQeER/), for those so inclined.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to check ... " if (columnSizingParameters[i] > windowWidth) { columns = --i; } " ? On the first column which is bigger then allowed you stop and take the one before. Because that one was still alright.

Comment: Yup your right. I changed it to that, but with a break at the end so I don't always end up with 12 columns. I also separated the calculateColumns() function in to two, calculateColumns(), which defines the columnSizingParameters[], and createColumns(), which does the creation. Looking at it again made me realize that there was no need to redefine columnSizingParameters every time the page is resized.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this was posted more than 2.5 years ago and you likely have learned a fair amount about JavaScript and/or jQuery in that time. Still this question hasn't had any answers (at the time of writing) so I would like to take out this [zombie](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1511/120114).

### Your Questions

> I used the defer attribute in my script tag and put it in the head. Is that acceptable? Is there a better way?

I believe that is acceptable, however there are other ways to have the code executed after certain events have occurred. For example, one could use [`event.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to trigger a function call after events occur, like [*DOMContentLoaded*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded).

As walter memtioned in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/196718/1575353) "-The Yahoo! Exceptional Performance team recommend [placing scripts at the bottom of your page](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom) because of the way browsers download components._" so one can consider putting the `<script>` tag in the `<body>` tag instead of the `<head>`.

> Setting intervals/timeouts still confounds me. How would you create a small interval between each number line printing, such that they print out sequentially and in an animated manner.

Yes, using `setTimeout()` would be a good way to achieve such a feature. a function that calls that function, passing a function to execute after a set amount of time could call the outer function until all elements have been printed, or similarly with `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()`.

### Review feedback

Overall I like the layout of the view. The code is organized well for the most part. There are a few recommendations I have, listed below.

---

The collection of `<div>` elements with class name `number-container` is stored in `fizzContainer` at the start of the script:

> ```
> var fizzContainer = $("div.number-container");
> ```

This is great, because whenever that collection is needed later, it can be utilize by that variable name. Sadly, I don't see that name utilized anywhere after it is assigned, thus the assignment seems superfluous... You could utilize that to replace the line below, in the resize callback:

> ```
> $(".number-container").replaceWith("<div class='number-container'></div>");
> ```

With a call to [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html):

```
fizzContainer.html('');
```

Assigning DOM collections to variables in the beginning could minimize DOM lookups for other collections, e.g. `$('h1')`, `$(".number-container")`.

---

In that resize function I see the following:

> ```
> $(window).resize(function(){
>   windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
>   calculateHeading(windowWidth);
> ```

It appears that `calculateHeading()` accepts the window width as a parameter, whereas all other functions just utilize the global variables. Why not use one tactic or the other?

I also noticed that in the codepen code three spaces are used for indentation in that resize callback function, while the code posted above uses two spaces.

---

If performance was an issue, I would recommend adding the columns after the contents have been added, and potentially adding the columns after all have been generated, so as to minimize [reflows](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/browser-reflow).